# CKEditor is html encoding when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, ckeditor

I have a test link; 
    `<a href="https//example.com?test=5&sectid=4"/>testLink`

In the ckeditor when I right click on a link and click "edit link", in the URL text box, where the link should say"&sectid=4" the editor has turned it into the section symbol §id=4.

in my config.js, I already have `config.entities = false`.

What else should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid writing the section symbol in the first place. The entity `&sect`, presumably (since you didn't show a proper [MCVE]), is being transformed into `§` by the browser before it even gets passed to the CKEditor JavaScript.

Write your HTML properly, if you want an ampersand as data in HTML then you need to present it as `&amp;` since `&` means "Start of entity".

```
<a href="https//example.com?test=5&amp;sectid=4"/>testLink
```

Comment: I agree. If this was only being used on my end that's how I would do it. Unfortunately, this is what clients will see and we can't expect (or I guess, don't want) them to have to write out the full entity.

Comment: If you're expecting them to write raw HTML then you should expect them to write out the full entity. Encourage them not to write raw HTML if they can't handle that.